# Eval not working with comparison

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In the following textbox, the text is populated with Minutely.

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" Runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FREQUENCY") %>' />
```

I am trying select a combobox item based on the prexisting frequency. This code gives me a object not set to an instance of an object error:

```
<telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="One Time Run" Value="OneTimeRun" Selected='<%# (Eval("FREQUENCY").ToString() == "OneTimeRun" ? true : false) %>' />
```

I have tried the following ways to no success:

```
<telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="One Time Run" Value="OneTimeRun" Selected='<%# (Eval("FREQUENCY").ToString() == "OneTimeRun") %>' />
<telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="One Time Run" Value="OneTimeRun" Selected='<%# Eval("FREQUENCY").ToString() == "OneTimeRun" ? true : false %>' />
```

I don't understand what is wrong. If my textbox is being populated with the text "Minutely", why am I getting this error when I want to do comparison.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you just can't use Eval on combo item since there's no datasource bound to it.

I suggest instead of trying to set Selected on your combo item, you should do the following: create a datasource of your items, bind the combo to the collection, set SelectedValue of the combo declaratively using Eval as you do now.